# Any way to get Bluetooth to work on MacBook 12″ Boot Camp?

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, bluetooth

I know that it’s not officially supported, but there is any manual way that I can get Bluetooth to work on a MacBook 12″ Windows Boot Camp partition?

Comment: What is a MacBook 12? Is that a model or year? I need a way to identify your Mac model and which version of windows you have installed.

Comment: It's s model, there is only one MacBook version outhere , i installed windows 8.1 , windows 7 isn't supported anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Boot Camp 6.0, it will let you use Bluetooth on the MacBook 2015.

Answer (score 0):

I searched my ass off to find a solution.

When i released, it might just be that the hardware is confuesed, and looked to the MacOSx bluetooth service some how...

So i logged back in to OSx, unpaird my Microsoft Sculpt Comfort Mouse... (Unpaird = make sure it is working, then activated the pairing mode, so it don't work :P)

Then i logged back into bootcamp... AND fu... yeah it worked!

I spent 4h online, and did't get anything to work. Now i feel stupid :P

Hope this Works for someone els aswell! (Sry for the bad English)

And you need Bootcamp 6 ofc :)